# How to Set Big Query Require Partition Filter in BQ Commandline

Tags: google-bigquery

When Creating a new empty partitioned table schema in Big Query Web GUI, you can SET the **Require Partition filter** Option.

How can I set the same option when creating a table using bq command-line tool. Right now my command is:

```
bq mk --table --time_partitioning_field event_time my_dataset.events event_id:INTEGER,event_time:TIMESTAMP
```

The command successfully creates the Partitioned Table, but I have not seen a flag for setting the Require Partition filter.

How can I edit the Option later after creating the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a bq command line version >= 2.0.30 you should see a --require_partition_filter option in the mk command. Please let us know if this is not the case. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to see you back on SO :o) ; your answer (back in time) were extremely helpful for me

Comment: Thank you @Pavan Edara. I updated my bq and got the option.

Comment: Is there a way to add --require_partition_filter option for the tables that are already created & partitioned?

Comment: You should be able to update the require_partition_filter property of a table by calling Tables.update

Answer (score 7):

To answer your second question:

```
bq update --require_partition_filter --time_partitioning_field=event_time my_dataset.events
```

Or with a fully qualified table name:

```
bq update --require_partition_filter --time_partitioning_field=event_time project-id:my_dataset.events
```

You can also disable with:

```
bq update --norequire_partition_filter --time_partitioning_field=event_time project-id:my_dataset.events
```