# How to Set Big Query Require Partition Filter in BQ Commandline With Ingestion Partition Tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to add a partition filter requirement to a table after creating it. I know one can do this for tables that are partitioned by a column thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286366) and kennethmac2000 but I this solution doesn't appear to work for ingestion date partitioned tables.

At first I tried

`bq update --require_partition_filter project:dataset.table`

and I then I tried

`bq update --time_partitioning_type DAY --require_partition_filter project:dataset.table`

and both result in...

`UpdateTable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'range_partitioning'`

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command "bq update" gives me "unexpected keyword argument" error when updating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865624/command-bq-update-gives-me-unexpected-keyword-argument-error-when-updating-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me on CLI version:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 215.0.0
beta 2018.07.16
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.09.04
gsutil 4.33
```

[image]

```
$ bq update --require_partition_filter --time_partitioning_type=DAY grey-sort-challenge:afl_ml.partition_filter_test
Table 'grey-sort-challenge:afl_ml.partition_filter_test' successfully updated.
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't expect the minor version difference to matter but this the result of gcloud --version: Google Cloud SDK 225.0.0, bq 2.0.37, core 2018.11.09, gsutil 4.34

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're doing wrong Stephan. But it works fine for me.