# Command "bq update" gives me "unexpected keyword argument" error when updating tables

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk

Newbie here. So I have started using Google's Big Query and have their Cloud SDK installed which helps me manipulate my data from the Command Prompt. Lately, however, I started getting this error message whenever I use the "bq update" command on a table.

`UpdateTable()` got an unexpected keyword argument `'range_partitioning'`

The complete command that I used is:

```
bq update --description "something something" some-project:Output_Tables.dummy
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I can't find anything in Big Query documentations about this error. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set Big Query Require Partition Filter in BQ Commandline With Ingestion Partition Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733463/how-to-set-big-query-require-partition-filter-in-bq-commandline-with-ingestion-p)

Comment: Try updating your `gcloud` version and give it another go..

Comment: Thanks, Graham Polley. Our problem does appear to be the same. And we have the exact same version of gcloud. I'll give updating a go. Will let you know what happens.

Comment: Cool. BTW, I just tested using your same command on my version of `gcloud` and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Lemwelle Rosales Have you managed to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is run 
`gcloud components update`
Looks like this was an error that they fixed
[First post so image link to change log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRCBt.png)